# Excel Copy whole row from a sheet to another sheet based on one column value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy an entire row from a sheet and paste in another sheet with same header consider a particular column value is equal to 89581.But my VBA throws 424 error.Please help.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim c As Range
Dim Row As Long
Dim sheetUse As Worksheet
Dim sheetCopy As Worksheet
Set sheetUse = Sheets("Data1").Select
Set sheetCopy = Sheets("Data2").Select
Row = 3 'Assume same  header in sheet2 as in sheet1
For Each c In sheetUse.Range("O3",  Sheet1.Range("O65536").End(xlUp))       
    If c = 89581 Then

         'copy this row to sheet2
        Row = Row + 1
        c.EntireRow.Copy sheetCopy.Cells(Row, 1)

    End If

Next c

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly get rid of .select when setting the sheets, I am just playing around rewriting this for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, build a reference to copy then copy and paste in one go.

```
Sub CopyToOtherSheet()
Dim sheetUse As Worksheet, sheetCopy As Worksheet, i As Long, CopyRange As String
Set sheetUse = Sheets("Data1")
Set sheetCopy = Sheets("Data2")
For i = 3 To sheetUse.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    If sheetUse.Cells(i, 15) = 89581 Then CopyRange = CopyRange & "," & i & ":" & i
Next i
sheetUse.Range(Right(CopyRange, Len(CopyRange) - 1)).Copy
sheetCopy.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Change to values or formats or whatever you want
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Assumed Data1 is the sheet with the data in and Data2 is the one to copy to.

Comment: It throws me "vba method range of object _worksheet failed error" in line number 8

Comment: Do you have a sheet called Data1 (with no space)